# Where are store wifi connection parameters?

Tags: wireless

When I do a fresh install of the distribution, one of the annoying things is that I lose all my wifi connection. Thus I would like to know in which file all data are stored (WEP key and SSID) in order to save it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using network manager (that is the default) then `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`. For every network there is a file in that directory.